# How to start Jenkins server on OSX on boot

Tags: macos, jenkins, server, boot

I have installed Jenkins on a Mac mini running Sierra using Homebrew but whenever I restart the computer I am unable to connect to it from another computer on the same LAN. I have to manually run the command jenkins in terminal to launch it & then it works. I followed various tutorials about LaunchDaemons & my plist file is present in that folder. I am not a Mac expert so can someone please guide me step by step? I just want to have it up & running automatically whenever the system reboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after much brain-wracking.

1. Installed Jenkins via Brew but stopped its service.
2. Created plist & saved it in LaunchDaemons folder with the filepath of version 2.66. The irritating thing is updating the path of Jenkins everytime it gets updated.
3. Launched it via **sudo launchctl** command.